# Warning: Apps with authentication require the experimental permission in the manifest.json?

Tags: google-chrome, authentication, google-chrome-extension

I want to integrate authentication into my chrome app, but I saw this warning here : https://developer.chrome.com/apps/app_codelab7_useridentification

`Warning: Apps with authentication require the experimental permission in the manifest.json and, until they came out of experimental state, they cannot be uploaded to the Chrome Web Store. If you prefer, you can choose to skip this lab.`

There seems to be a grammatical error in the warning @ `"until they came out of experimental state"` which made it ambiguous to read.
Does this mean I cannot publish an app with this feature until the feature comes out of experimental state? Or until the app comes out of experimental state?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Chrome Identity API is no longer experimental. The [current page](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/identity) says "Stable since Chrome 29."